# From a sequence in a Hilbert space $H$ to a countable set of linearly independent vectors.

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, vector-spaces, proof-writing

Let $(y_n)_n$ be a sequence in $H$. Then exists an at most countable set of linearly independent vectors $(x_j)_{j\in J}$ in $H$ such that $$\text{sp}\left(y_n\;|\; n\in\mathbb{N}\right)=\text{sp}\left(x_j\;|\; j\in J\right).$$

**$\large \text{My attempt.}$**

> For any $j=0,1,\dots$, let $k_j$ be a first integer $k\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $$\dim\text{sp}(\{y_1,\dots, y_k\})=j.$$ Now if we define $x_j:=y_{k_j}$, how can I prove that $$\text{sp}(x_1,\dots, x_j)=\text{sp}(y_1,\dots, y_{k_j})$$

Could you give me a hints?

Comment: @GiorgosGiapitzakis No. This must be shown without G.S., In Gram-Schmidt procedure we start from a linearly independent set, instead here the starting sequence is generic.

Comment: I missed that sorry

Comment: You can apply induction with respect to $j.$ For $k_j\le k<k_{j+1}$ we have $\dim\operatorname{span}\{y_1,\ldots, y_k\}=j,$ hence $y_k$ belongs to $$\operatorname{span}\{y_1, y_2,\ldots, y_{k_j}\}\underset{\rm induction}{=}\operatorname{span}\{y_{k_1},y_{k_2},\ldots, y_{k_j}\}$$ Thus 
$$\operatorname{span}\{y_1, y_2,\ldots, y_{k_{j+1}-1}\}=\operatorname{span}\{y_{k_1},y_{k_2},\ldots, y_{k_j}\}$$ Hence
$$\operatorname{span}\{y_1, y_2,\ldots, y_{k_{j+1}-1},y_{k{j+1}}\}=\operatorname{span}\{y_{k_1},y_{k_2},\ldots, y_{k_j},y_{k_{j+1}}\}$$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Thanks! Excuse me, but I don't understand

Comment: Sorry that my comment is unclear. I just use $y_{k_j}=x_j$ and prove the equality $$\operatorname{span}\{y_1, y_2,\ldots, y_{k_j}\}=\operatorname{span}\{y_{k_1},y_{k_2},\ldots, y_{k_j}\}$$ by induction with respect to $j.$

Comment: Just throw out any $y_j$ that is in the span of $y_1, \dots, y_{j - 1}$.

Comment: I don't understand why you consider $y_{k_{j+1}-1}$